# Why doesn't this project euler #19 code work? (Python)

Tags: python

I made a code for project euler's #19 problem in Python, and it doesn't give me the right answer.
The question is: You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
Thirty days has September,
April, June and November.
All the rest have thirty-one,
Saving February alone,
Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
And on leap years, twenty-nine.
A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

What is the problem here?:

```
months = {'January': 31,
     'February': 28,
     'March': 31,
     'April': 30,
     'May': 31,
     'June': 30,
     'July': 31,
     'August': 31,
     'September': 30,
     'November': 30,
     'December': 31
     }

years = range(1900, 2001)    

day = 1

def main():
    global day
    for year in years:
        if year % 4 == 0 or year % 400 == 0:
            months['February'] = 29
        else:
            months['February'] = 28

        for month in months:
            if months[month] == 31:
                day += 31 % 7 +1
            while day > 7:
                day = day - 7
            if day == 1:
                yield day


result = sum(main())
print (result)
```

Also it generates different answers everytime I use,

Thanks :)

Comment: `day += 31 % 7 +1` is equivalent to `day += 4`.

Comment: 1. Why start from year 1900? shouldn't it be 1901? 2.The condition for leap year seems incorrect. year%4==0 and year%100!=0 3.in the month loop, why do you just test if a month has 31 days?

Comment: I started from 1900 because they said in the info that the 1st of January 1900 was monday.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the algorithm and your code. But I can say about this.

`it generates different answers everytime I use`

Probably you forgot to initialize `month`, `year` and `day` before executing `result = sum(main())`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be simpler, if you use [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
In [16]: from datetime import datetime
In [17]: from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

In [18]: current = datetime(1901, 1, 1)
In [19]: end = datetime(2001, 1, 1)
In [20]: ans = 0

In [21]: while current < end:
   ....:     if current.weekday() == 6:
   ....:         ans += 1                          
   ....:     current += relativedelta(months=1)
   ....:     

In [22]: ans
Out[22]: 171
```